# How to simplify the D.E to bring it to the Linear form?

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

The D.E is :
$$\frac{dy}{dx}=1-x(x-y)-x^3(y-x)^2$$
Here the only problem is how to simplify the equation into the standard linear differential equation. After the solution the equation can be solved by the bernoulli's form:
I have even tried the form 
$$Mdx+Ndy=0$$
where we compare the whether the $$\frac{\partial M}{\partial y}=\frac{\partial N}{\partial x}$$
But in this method the equations become very complex so:
Can any one suggest some method?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Substitute $y=z+x$ and the equation becomes $z'+1=1+xz-x^3z^2$ or $z'=xz-x^3z^2$. Substitute $z=e^{\frac{x^2}{2}}w$ and this becomes $e^{\frac{x^2}{2}}w'=-x^3e^{x^2}w^2$ or $-\frac{w'}{w^2}=x^3e^{\frac{x^2}{2}}$.

We can now integrate to get $\frac{1}{w}=x^2e^{\frac{x^2}{2}}-2e^{\frac{x^2}{2}}+C$, so $z=\frac{e^{\frac{x^2}{2}}}{x^2e^{\frac{x^2}{2}}-2e^{\frac{x^2}{2}}+C}$.

Comment: Well the answer provided in the book is $\frac{1}{y-x}=-x^2-2+Ce^{\frac{x^2}{2}}$ I think your answer after simplification may be same.@almagest

Comment: You were probably expected to identify the equation after the first step as a Bernoulli type equation.